# Challenge with storing data in mysquel

Tags: storing-data

Please how do I store GVC/AK/CR/1/2017/001 in SQL? I use Mysql with popsql as my text editor this is the line I was trying to store:

```
INSERT INTO clients (name, phone_no, plan_no, job_remark, quater, year,) 
VALUES ('UAE GEO', 07037695328, 'GVC/AK/CR/1/2017/001', 'revalidation', 1, '2017-03-28');
```

This was the error message I got:

> ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') VALUES ('UAE GEO', 07037695328, 'GVC/AK/CR/1/2017/001', 'revalidation', 1, '20' at line 1

Please help. thanks

Comment: You have an extra ',' after year in your SQL insert statement.

Comment: What have you tried to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO clients (name, phone_no, plan_no, job_remark, quater, year,)
VALUES (name='UAE GEO', phone_no= 07037695328, plan_no='GVC/AK/CR/1/2017/001', job_remark='revalidation', quarter=1, year='2017-03-28');
```

Comment: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') VALUES (name= 'UAE GEO', phone_no= 07037695328, plan_no= 'GVC/AK/CR/1/2017/001' at line 1

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it